# How to retain old value in AJAX drop down using laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am developing application in laravel 9.I have dependent dropdown in my application .
I have used ajax for dependent dropdown. It is working .But When I submit the form it is not showing selected option .It is showing "please select line"
I have used old() .But it is not working.
Here is my code

```
$("#downtimedatepicker").change(function(){
       var downtimedate = $(this).val();

       if(downtimedate)
       {
          $.ajax({
              url:"{{ url('downtimeline') }}",
              type : "POST",
              data: {
                  downtimedate: downtimedate
              },
              dataType : "json",
              success:function(data)
              { 
                if(data){
                   $('select[name="line"]').empty();
                   $.each(data,function(key,value) {
                       $('select[name="line"]').append('<option value="'+ value +'" {{ old('line') == "'value'" ? 'selected' : '' }}>'+value+'</option>');
                   });  
                 } else{
                   $("#line").empty();
                 }
              }
          });
     }
});
```

Mycontrollercode
public function getdowntimeline(Request $request){
$downtimedate=$request->downtimedate;
$downtimelines=Downtime::where('date', $downtimedate)->distinct()->pluck('line', 'id')->unique();
return json_encode($downtimelines);
}

It should show selected option when I submit the form

Comment: When you use ajax need create all need data by self in controller.. its JS.. You can look on created js use devTool. old() work via native laravel form

Comment: pls, show your controller for `url('downtimeline')` and example of returned data. You need  remember previously selected items and reassign. But without a concrete example it is difficult to suggest something. In any case, the JS logic should contain a minimum of PHP dependencies

Comment: same issue .did you find a solution ??